# Blow_fish implementation in java, need to verify/check with php BCrypted string

Tags: java, php, bcrypt, blowfish

This is my scenario: A String has been hashed by Hash::make() and the result stored into DB

```
$2a$10$O6gVauDNsdYP9KIKyShAfuQ9dj/Q2ET5UlzC4vVM3feimFTY11AzK
```

What i needed to do is: The input string can be anything. That has to be checked with the DB value whether it is matching or not in java by using Blow_fish algorithm. I knew that i can do the same bcrypt technic in java to check, but my requirement is to check the blow_fish encrypted text with bcrypted string. Is this possible?